# Update class every time one of kwargs is updated

Tags: python, oop

I have this small snippet of code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, not_used, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
        self.not_used = not_used
        self.f = ''
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.f=self.f+key+str(value)

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = A(100, x=1, y=2, z=3)
    print(a.f)
```

The output is `x1y2z3`. I would like for instances of class `a` to update all instance variables any time  a member of kwargs (and kwargs only) is updated. An example of this is:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    a = A(100, x=1, y=2, z=3)
    a.x = 2
    print(a.f)
```

For which the output would be `x2y2z3`. Is there a clean and elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you show an example of how you propose to "update" the kwargs dict? That name ceases to exist after the `__init__` call finishes.

Comment: Please see added example

Comment: Have you looked at the class method `__str__`?

Comment: @KyleL In reality I am not printing out a string. I have more complicated methods which have nothing to do with string representation. The content of `self.f` is there just as an example....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by making `f` a property.

For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, not_used, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
        self.not_used = not_used
    @property
    def f(self):
        return "".join(key+str(value) for key, value in self.__dict__.items())

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = A(100, x=1, y=2, z=3)
    print(a.f)
    a.y = 4
    print(a.f)
```

or, in order to only the keys which were in `kwargs` at `__init__` time, but might have changed subsequently:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, not_used, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
        self._keys = kwargs.keys()
        self.not_used = not_used
    @property
    def f(self):
        return "".join(key+str(self.__dict__[key]) for key in self._keys)

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = A(100, x=1, y=2, z=3)
    print(a.f)
    a.y = 4
    print(a.f)
```

Comment: Sorry but this throws an error: `NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined`

Comment: @user32882 Thank you for the information. Of course it does; `kwargs` is limited to the constructor. The data contained in it is added to `self.__dict__`, so we can use it from there (hopefully).

Comment: Ah... but the output to the code now is `x1y2z3not_used100
x1y4z3not_used100`. I only wish for kwargs to be used.

Comment: @user32882 Changed.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for finishing it up.